# Union of two MDX queries with FILTER clause

Tags: ssas, mdx, business-intelligence, mdx-query

I am a MDX beginner and want to union the below 2 MDX queries. I need help with the syntax because I tried using the union(Query 1 ,Query 2) , according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/union-mdx?view=sql-server-ver16), but that did not work. Gave me a syntax error.
Can someone please help?

Query 1:

```
WITH  
SET [SET_0] AS FILTER({[4MPGN3SA8-CALYEAR].[LEVEL01].MEMBERS}, [4MPGN3SA8-CALYEAR].[24MPGN3SA8-CALYEAR] = "2023")  
SET [SET_1] AS FILTER({[4MPGN3SA8-MKATEG].[LEVEL01].MEMBERS}, [4MPGN3SA8-MKATEG].[24MPGN3SA8-MKATEG] = "B")  
SET [SET_2] AS FILTER({[4MPGN3SA8-MSALESORG].[LEVEL01].MEMBERS}, [4MPGN3SA8-MSALESORG].[24MPGN3SA8-MSALESORG] = "48")  
SET [SET_3] AS FILTER({[4MPGN3SA8-MUSERID].[LEVEL01].MEMBERS},  NOT 
            (([4MPGN3SA8-MUSERID].[24MPGN3SA8-MUSERID] = "GERSD" OR 
            [4MPGN3SA8-MUSERID].[24MPGN3SA8-MUSERID] = "SEFBJ" OR 
            [4MPGN3SA8-MUSERID].[24MPGN3SA8-MUSERID] = "EWSDR" OR 
            [4MPGN3SA8-MUSERID].[24MPGN3SA8-MUSERID] = "UERDW")) ) 
SELECT 
 [SET_0] * 
 [SET_1] * 
 [4MPGN3SA8-MDATAID].[LEVEL01].MEMBERS * 
[4MPGN3SA8-SBMATH09].[LEVEL01].MEMBERS * 
[4MPGN3SA8-SBCUSTHE].[LEVEL01].MEMBERS * 
[SET_2] * 
[4MPGN3SA8-MYTIMEID].[LEVEL01].MEMBERS * 
[SET_3] DIMENSION PROPERTIES 
[4MPGN3SA8-CALYEAR].[24MPGN3SA8-CALYEAR], 
[4MPGN3SA8-MDATAID].[24MPGN3SA8-MDATAID], 
[4MPGN3SA8-MYTIMEID].[24MPGN3SA8-MYTIMEID], 
[4MPGN3SA8-MUSERID].[24MPGN3SA8-MUSERID] ON ROWS, 
{[Measures].[2ITVVC55PTEG9SLL3FXJQL20C]} ON COLUMNS FROM 
[MPGN3SA8/GMMPA_MPGN3SA8_Q0001]
```

Query 2:

```
WITH  
SET [SET_0] AS FILTER({[4MPGN3SA8-CALYEAR].[LEVEL01].MEMBERS}, [4MPGN3SA8-CALYEAR].[24MPGN3SA8-CALYEAR] = "2023")  
SET [SET_1] AS FILTER({[4MPGN3SA8-MKATEG].[LEVEL01].MEMBERS}, [4MPGN3SA8-MKATEG].[24MPGN3SA8-MKATEG] = "B")  
SET [SET_2] AS FILTER({[4MPGN3SA8-MSALESORG].[LEVEL01].MEMBERS}, [4MPGN3SA8-MSALESORG].[24MPGN3SA8-MSALESORG] = "56")  
SET [SET_3] AS FILTER({[4MPGN3SA8-MUSERID].[LEVEL01].MEMBERS},  NOT 
            (([4MPGN3SA8-MUSERID].[24MPGN3SA8-MUSERID] = "GERSD" OR 
            [4MPGN3SA8-MUSERID].[24MPGN3SA8-MUSERID] = "SEFBJ" OR 
            [4MPGN3SA8-MUSERID].[24MPGN3SA8-MUSERID] = "EWSDR" OR 
            [4MPGN3SA8-MUSERID].[24MPGN3SA8-MUSERID] = "UERDW")) ) 
SELECT 
 [SET_0] * 
 [SET_1] * 
 [4MPGN3SA8-MDATAID].[LEVEL01].MEMBERS * 
[4MPGN3SA8-SBMATH09].[LEVEL01].MEMBERS * 
[4MPGN3SA8-SBCUSTHE].[LEVEL01].MEMBERS * 
[SET_2] * 
[4MPGN3SA8-MYTIMEID].[LEVEL01].MEMBERS * 
[SET_3] DIMENSION PROPERTIES 
[4MPGN3SA8-CALYEAR].[24MPGN3SA8-CALYEAR], 
[4MPGN3SA8-MDATAID].[24MPGN3SA8-MDATAID], 
[4MPGN3SA8-MYTIMEID].[24MPGN3SA8-MYTIMEID], 
[4MPGN3SA8-MUSERID].[24MPGN3SA8-MUSERID] ON ROWS, 
{[Measures].[2ITVVC55PTEG9SLL3FXJQL20C]} ON COLUMNS FROM 
[MPGN3SA8/GMMPA_MPGN3SA8_Q0001]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use UNION in MDX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54072203/how-to-use-union-in-mdx)